# Bind the Username in all Pages

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

HI 
i'm developing a software(WPF) and i will insert a feature but i don't know how work out it.
I have a Window Login (username,Password)to enter in the software after that the user insert the credentials appear a MainWindow and i have a textblock(txt_Username) to store the Username of the Window Login  in this MainWindow.Now in the MainWindow i have a Frame that store the Page from the TreeView  in this way:

```
  <Frame  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="frSample_LoadCompleted" Navigating="frSample_Navigating" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="frSample" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewForm, Path=SelectedItem.XamlFilePath, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=Benvenuto.xaml}"/>
```

..so i can navigate in my apps using the TreeView ,
In My apps i have a lot of Pages so  my feature is create a textBlock in each page and store  textBlock (txt_Username) from the MainWindow so in each page appear the Name of the User Login but i don't know how work out this feature ...Do you have any idea how i can do this feature?

Thanks so much

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
User.Identity.Name
```

on anypage if you are using asp Membership (which I assume you are) to display to logged in name.

Comment: Thanks for your response waqasahmed,
i use Thread.CurrentPrinciple.Name ,for my poor knowledge i did not study yet Asp :(.
Cheers